# In-universe, what was Legolas doing during the events of The Hobbit (book version)?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

In the Peter Jackson *The Hobbit* movies, we see that Legolas was one of the elves that personally captured the dwarves in Mirkwood forest, pursued them down the river, fought some Orcs in Lake Town, and fought in the Battle of Five armies ([defying physics along the way](https://www.wired.com/2015/04/laws-physics-not-apply-legolas/)).

In the book version of *The Hobbit*, what was Legolas doing? Was this explained in any of the appendices or something?

I don't think that this is a duplicate of [Is Legolas in The Hobbit Book?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/60601/13217) because that asks about it from an out-of-universe perspective and I am wondering about it from an in-universe perspective.

Comment: Chilling in the Woodland Realm. Practicing his bow and arrow.

Comment: @Valorum While similar, that doesn't seem to be answering from an in-universe perspective what he was actually doing.

Comment: The second answer in the proposed duplicate seems to address this.

Comment: Agreed.  The second answer in the proposed duplicate is sufficient.